# Could not register pre-delete validatation plugin step for the Team entity in MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to add validation before Team entity deletion. In order to do that, I need to add Pre-validation plugin step for the Delete message and Team entity.

Nevertheless, when I'm trying to do it via the Plugin Registration Tool, I'm getting an error:

> Invalid Entity Name
>
> Invalid Primary Entity or Secondary Entity specified. Please re-enter the data.

Here is the data I'm filling in the Register New Step:

- **Message:** Delete
- **Primary Entity:** team
- **Secondary Entity:** none
- **Run in User's Context:** Calling User
- **Execution Order:** 1
- **Eventing Pipeline Stage of Execution:** Pre-validation
- **Execution Mode:** Synchronous
- **Deployment:** Server

I'm using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011.

I could not find any explanation for that. What I'm asking is:

1. What is the reason for that?
2. What is the intended way of applying custom validations during the deletion of the Team entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to enable registering the plug-in by updating the corresponding SdkMessageFilterBase record.

1. Connect to your DB server.
2. Navigate to your **%ORGANIZATION_NAME%_MSCRM** DB.
3. Run the script:

```
  SELECT
      [dbo].[SdkMessageFilterBase].[PrimaryObjectTypeCode],
      [dbo].[SdkMessageFilterBase].[CustomizationLevel],
      [dbo].[SdkMessageFilterBase].[SecondaryObjectTypeCode],
      [dbo].[SdkMessageFilterBase].[IsCustomProcessingStepAllowed],
      [dbo].[SdkMessageFilterBase].[Availability],
      [dbo].[SdkMessageFilterBase].[SdkMessageId],
      [dbo].[SdkMessageFilterBase].[IsVisible]
  FROM
      [dbo].[SdkMessageFilterBase]
      INNER JOIN [dbo].[SdkMessageBase]
          ON [dbo].[SdkMessageFilterBase].[SdkMessageId] = [dbo].[SdkMessageBase].[SdkMessageId]
  WHERE
      [dbo].[SdkMessageBase].[Name] = 'Delete' AND
      [dbo].[SdkMessageFilterBase].[PrimaryObjectTypeCode] = 9 -- Team entity code is 9
```

4. Check the result. If `IsCustomProcessingStepAllowed` field is set to 0, it is preventing you from registering the plug-in step.
5. Update `IsCustomProcessingStepAllowed` to 1 to be able to register custom plug-in step.

This solution worked for me.

Articles describing such solution:

- [Enabling plug-in for Change Business Unit and Change Manager for systemuser entity](https://nishantrana.me/2010/04/29/enabling-plug-in-for-change-business-unit-and-change-manager-for-systemuser-entity/)

Comment: Just wanted to call it out: “This is unsupported”

Comment: @ArunVinoth, unsupported "out-of-the-box". And I wonder - why?

Answer (score 0):

That's because Delete Message for Team Entity in CRM 2011 is not supported

[image]

Whereas when you look for CRM 2016 and above Team Entity does support delete Message

[image]

Summary: CRM 2011 Team Entity does not support Delete Message